# Google Site Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have created an approval workflow in Google Sites. When I submit a request to a manager.
[image]

He approves the request from the GMail <kbd>Approve</kbd> button, but it displays an error that he doesn't have permission:

[image]

I have shared my Google Site to him, and he can edit this Google Site:

[image]

But why couldn't he approve the request from the GMail <kbd>Approve</kbd> button?

[image]

I found that if I create a script from Google Drive, there is a <kbd>Share</kbd> button, but if I create Apps Script from Google Sites, there isn't a <kbd>Share</kbd> button:

[image]

[image]

How could I do this? How could the manager use this Google Site approval workflow?

Answer (score 0):

How does the script run and who had access to it. There are 3 (or4) access levels for any web app - only you, anyone in the domain, anyone, anyone including anonymous. 
Have you set the appropriate access permission for your app.

Comment: User submit a request from Google Site, there is a button in Google Site, and the manager approve request from G-mail, all of the process Google Site Apps Script run. I have set the Google Site access permission "Who has access to the app:" at "anyone, anyone including anonymous".

Comment: So far no people could help me.

Comment: What does the approve button do ? Also, under whose id does the script run ?